# Where I can modify twitter oauth sheme and host?

Tags: android, twitter, twitter-oauth, twitter4j

Before about 2 month, I create android app and add twitter app in twitter developers.

And I did oauth with twitter.

**strings.xml**

```
<string name="twitter_sign_in_scheme">myappname</string>
<string name="twitter_sign_in_host">twitter</string>
```

**AndroidMenifest**

```
<activity android:name=".TwitterLinkActivity" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <data
                android:scheme="@string/twitter_sign_in_scheme"
                android:host="@string/twitter_sign_in_host" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

It did and does work fine.

Now I need to modify scheme and host. But I can not find where to modify.

In my memory, callback url contains oauth scheme and host.

But my twitter app setting does not contain. (See below image) But Oauth works.

[image]

My eyes are crazy...? I can not find where...

Please let me know where to modify twitter oauth scheme and host.

Answer (score 0):

Oh my god....

Twitter Oauth url settings are not in online...

I set in code when get request token...

```
TwitterFactory.getSingleton().getOAuthRequestToken(
                context.getString(R.string.twitter_sign_in_scheme)+"://"
                +context.getString(R.string.twitter_sign_in_host) );
```